Get world bounding box of SCNNode
How can we obtain the world bounding box of an SCNNode through code?
My code to get the local bounding box:
extension SCNNode {
    func getLocalNodeBoundingBox() -> (width: Float, height: Float, depth: Float) {
        let (min, max) = boundingBox
        return (width: max.x - min.x, height: max.y - min.y, depth: max.z - min.z)
    }
}



Calculate the bounding box for root node and it will give your world bounding box
